# ClassNotFoundException when finding generic type of a declared java.util.Map field on a JPA entity (GlassFish 3)

Tags: java, jpa, reflection, glassfish, classloader

I need to dynamically find the class of a java.util.Map subtype instance being a declared field on a JPA entity, here the `EventDetail` instances in the `details` map:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "EVENTS" )
public class Event implements Serializable
{
    ...

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "event", fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @MapKey( name = "key" )
    private Map<String, EventDetail> details;

    ...

    public Map<String, EventDetail> getDetails()
    {
        return ( this.details );
    }

    ...
}
```

EventDetail is nothing special:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "EVENT_DETAILS" )
public class EventDetail implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1425743343118085745L;

    @Id
    @Column( name = "EVENT_DETAIL_ID" )
    private Long              id;

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false )
    @JoinColumn( name = "EVENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "EVENT_ID" )
    private Event             event;

    ...
}
```

The mappings are correct, assume that. The code to process is in a CDI bean and goes like:

```
// clazz is the one declaring the map: find generic type (of value)!
ParameterizedType mapType = ( ParameterizedType ) clazz.getDeclaredField( "details" ).getGenericType();
Type mapValueType = mapType.getActualTypeArguments()[1]; // get EventDetail type

Class<?> mapValueClass = Class.forName( mapValueType.toString() ); // FAIL: CNFE!
// Class<?> mapValueClass = Class.forName( mapValueType.toString(), true, EventDetail.class.getClassLoader() );
// Class<?> mapValueClass = Class.forName( mapValueType.toString(), true, clazz.getClassLoader() );
// Class<?> mapValueClass = Class.forName( mapValueType.toString(), true, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() );

Method mapGetMethod = method.getReturnType().getMethod( "get", Object.class );

methods.add( mapGetMethod );

// set return type to whatever the map defines
clazz = mapValueClass;
```

I get `ClassNotFoundException` when calling any of the `Class.forName()` variants:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class tld.company.compliance.coiresultmgmt.entity.EventDetail
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at tld.company.coi.resultmgmt.view.BaseEventHistoryManager.getHistoryStringValuesFor(BaseEventHistoryManager.java:926)
.
.
.
```

**Q:**
What am I doing wrong? How do I get the class?

This is in a GlassFish 3.2.1 env. using EclipseLink 2.3 as JPA provider.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Type.toString()` outputs `"class "` before the actual class name, like `"class tld.company.compliance.coiresultmgmt.entity.EventDetail"`. This is shown in the stacktrace, but it can get overlooked easily.

You need to remove that part of course, e.g. like

```
String typeString = mapValueType.toString();

// cut type from type string, otherwise CNFE!
Class<?> mapValueClass = Class.forName( typeString.substring( typeString.indexOf( ' ' ) + 1 ) );
```